# Firefox - Collecting the data used by LAB.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox, graph

I have a device - Stiebel Eltron heat pump -  home and I can track it with a web interface.
[image]

I can only access the previous month and the current month.
But I would like to keep the all the data, in a numeric way rather than having it like images.

Comment: First things I need to do is get inspiration for how to connect to the page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5119861/record-http-form-posts-via-a-browser

Comment: I dont think thats the data you would want to extract. The jquery code might be doing some manipulations on the data and creating this canvas

Comment: The data I want is data that will allow me extrapolating temperature measures from my device. At some point it must be downloaded to my browser, in some format, right?

Comment: yes that is true, But the one in the image is not the actual data. I mean the one in the inspect element. You can check the Network tab for all the requests sent and data received. You can then write a small code to hit this url and then save data to file as you want. But that depends on how the server accepts requests from unknown domain

Comment: I am willing to find out the trick... I'll ask their tech support.

Comment: @Reddy, you are right. It uses angularjs.1.0.6, and I get the raw data from of of the GETs displayed thanks to Firebug.

Comment: Chrome also might be useful, also you can install firebug in Mozilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first place I must get the raw data. I know how to do it with Firefox and Firebug addin to copy/paste the data to a file... manually. It uses `angularjs.1.0.6`, and I get the raw data from one of the GETs displayed thanks to Firebug:

```
GET https://thesite/api/data/1036493/heatEnergy/today?noCacheDummyValue=1459148624909
GET https://thesite/api/data/1036493/outTemp/today?noCacheDummyValue=1459148624905
GET https://thesite/api/data/1036493/heatEnergy/lastMonth?noCacheDummyValue=1459148708330
GET https://thesite/api/data/1036493/outTemp/lastMonth?noCacheDummyValue=1459148708321
```

It yould be better if I could do it 
 - by hacking directly into the LAB.min.js data?
 - by calling `curl` with my usual login post, then collect data with the `GET`s above

Here is how my `curl` login `POST` call looks like:

```
    curl -o myraw.data --data-urlencode "userName=tutu&password=xx"  'https://thesite/api/login?noCacheDummyValue=1458825357449' \
     -H 'Host: thesite' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0' \
     -H 'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
     -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8' \
     -H 'Referer: https://thesite/mobile/app/app.html' \
     -H 'Content-Length: 44' -H 'Cookie: JSESSIONID=1m5aputqimremdk95fgbtmgo9'  \
     -H 'Proxy-Authorization: Basic ??' -H 'DNT: 1'   \
     -H 'Connection: keep-alive'
```

But I get nothing. For now, I am happy with the `Firebug` `Copy Response Body / Paste` functionality.

Now I get my raw data looking like some JSON thing I guess:

```
[{"values":
[{"options":null,"webId":null,"value":"8.9","date":1458842750000,"writeValue":null,"unit":null}
,"options":null,"webId":null,"value":"9.1","date":1458842451000,"writeValue":null,"unit":null}
,{"options":null, 
...
,{"options":null,"webId":null,"value":"5.5","date":1458774051000,"writeValue":null,"unit":null}],"unit":"°C"}]
```

Now I got my data, I thought it would be easy. But I am getting headache trying to do something with this JSON data... I know some did try already: [Does LibreOffice Calc support JSON file importing/sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22534203/does-libreoffice-calc-support-json-file-importing-sorting/36210005#36210005)

I just have regular pattern in my JSON, and recently (re)discovered `sed`. So I use my new power (and how difficult it was to find I had to add a real line break in my substitute value):

```
cat rawdata.txt | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/},{/\
/g' | sed 's/"options":null,"webId":null,"value"://' |\
sed 's/,"writeValue":null,"unit":null//' |sed 's/,"date":/;/' |\
sed 's/\[{"values":\[{//' |sed 's/}\],"unit":"°C"}\]/\
    /' | sed 's/}\],"unit":"kWh"}\]/\
    /' > pureData.csv
```

And get my data like `"temperature"` / `"timestamp"`:

```
ju@ju-HP-Compaq-dc7900-Small-Form-Factor:~/INSTALL/myproj$ cat pureData.csv
"8.9";1458842750000
"9.1";1458842451000
"9.3";1458842150000
"9.4";1458841851000
"9.7";1458841550000
"9.9";1458841251000
"10.0";1458840950000
...
```

... so happy at this point! When I plot it, it looks like what I have in my Firefox window!

[image]
NB: I calculate that my time axis is based on a *number of milliseconds since 01.01.1970*.

If anyone interested, I wrote something to retrieve data with `curl` there: [How to use linux curl to login and retrieve data once logged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36315280/how-to-use-linux-curl-to-login-and-retreive-data-once-logged/36461565#36461565)